# Java swing change JTables content when JButton pressed

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jbutton, jcombobox

I was trying to develop a calendar app in java swing.I have 2 JComboBoxes to select year and month, and a JButton. When JButton pressed, my calendar should appear and show the chosen month of the chosen year. And when other year and month is chosen, and the button is pressed, my calendar should display the newly chosen month. But mine only works when the button is clicked for the first time, after that my calendars data doesn't change. Here is the code for Calendartable class and a minimal reproductive example. Could somebody please help me find the problem?

Calendartable class:

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;

public class Calendartable extends AbstractTableModel{
    
     public static String[] COLUMN_NAMES = {"Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday","Sunday"};
     private int tablerows = 0;

     private Date startOfWeek;
     private Date startDate;
     private Date endDate;
     
     public Calendartable(Date start, Date end) {
         this.startDate=start;
         this.endDate=end;
         
         Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
         cal.setTime(startDate);
         int i=0;
         while (cal.getTime().before(endDate)) {
             cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 7);
             tablerows++;
         }
         tablerows++;

         
         if (tablerows > 0) {
        

             cal.setTime(startDate);
             while (cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) != Calendar.MONDAY) {

                 cal.add(Calendar.DATE, -1);
             }

             startOfWeek = cal.getTime();
             

         }
         
     }

    @Override
    public int getRowCount() {
        return tablerows;
    }

    @Override
    public int getColumnCount() {
        return 7;
    }
    
     @Override
     public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
         return Date.class;
     }

     @Override
     public String getColumnName(int column) {
         return COLUMN_NAMES[column];
     }

    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
         Date date = null;

         if (startOfWeek != null) {

             Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
             cal.setTime(startOfWeek);
             int day = (rowIndex * 7) + columnIndex;            
             cal.add(Calendar.DATE, day);

             if (cal.getTime().before(startDate) || cal.getTime().after(endDate)) {
                 date = null;
             } else {
                 date = cal.getTime();           
             }
         }
         return date;
    }

}
```

And a reproductive example:

```
import java.awt.CardLayout;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;



public class Calendar2 {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Calendar");
    JPanel panelCont = new JPanel();
    JPanel panelFirst = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
    JTable table;
    
    JButton showbuttonmonth=new JButton("Show");
    JComboBox jcbyear;
    JComboBox<String> jcbmonth;
    
    CardLayout cl = new CardLayout();
    

    
    Object month[]=new Object[12];{
        month[0]="January";
        month[1]="February";
        month[2]="March";
        month[3]="April";
        month[4]="May";
        month[5]="June";
        month[6]="July";
        month[7]="August";
        month[8]="September";
        month[9]="October";
        month[10]="November";
        month[11]="December";
    }
    
    Object year[]=new Object[30];{
        for(int i=2010;i<=2039;i++)
            year[i-2010]=i;
    }
    
    public Calendar2() {
        panelCont.setLayout(cl);
        
        GridBagConstraints gbc=new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.insets=new Insets(5,5,5,5);
        
        
        
        
jcbyear=new JComboBox(year);
        
        gbc.insets=new Insets(15,0,0,5);
        gbc.gridx=0;
        gbc.gridy=2;
        panelFirst.add(new JLabel("Year:"),gbc);
        
        gbc.insets=new Insets(0,0,5,5);
        gbc.gridx=0;
        gbc.gridy=3;
        panelFirst.add(jcbyear, gbc);
        
        gbc.insets=new Insets(15,0,0,5);
        gbc.gridx=1;
        gbc.gridy=2;
        panelFirst.add(new JLabel("Month:"),gbc);
        
        
        jcbmonth=new JComboBox(month);
        gbc.insets=new Insets(0,0,5,5);
        gbc.gridx=1;
        gbc.gridy=3;
        panelFirst.add(jcbmonth, gbc);
        
        gbc.gridx=2;
        gbc.gridy=3;
        panelFirst.add(showbuttonmonth, gbc);
        
        gbc.gridx=1;
        gbc.gridy=4;
        
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM.dd.yyyy");
         Date startDate = null;
        try {
            startDate = sdf.parse("1.1.2010");
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
         Date endDate = null;
        try {
            endDate = sdf.parse("1.31.2010");
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
         table = new JTable(new Calendartable(startDate, endDate));
         panelFirst.add(new JScrollPane(table), gbc);
         
         
         panelCont.add(panelFirst, "1");
        cl.show(panelCont, "1");
        
        
        showbuttonmonth.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                int year = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(jcbyear.getSelectedItem()));
                
                int month=jcbmonth.getSelectedIndex()+1;
                
                String start=month+".1."+year;
                String end=month+".31."+year;
                
                gbc.gridx=1;
                gbc.gridy=4;
                
                SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM.dd.yyyy");
                 Date startDate = null;
                try {
                    startDate = sdf.parse(start);
                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                 Date endDate = null;
                try {
                    endDate = sdf.parse(end);
                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                 table = new JTable(new Calendartable(startDate, endDate));
                 panelFirst.add(new JScrollPane(table), gbc);
                
            }
        });
        
    }
    
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Calendar2 cal=new Calendar2();
        }

}
```

Comment: For one, you're creating a new JTable when the best solution is to much more simply replace the model of the existing JTable. Create a new DefaultTableModel and then call `setModel(newModel)` on the existing JTable.

Comment: But more importantly for this site, you're asking about code that is not behaving correctly and posting code snippets that we can't compile, run or test. Better to create a new program a [mre] and post this in your question. Please check out the link which will explain what this is.

Comment: Maybe this article, [Swing Calendar GUI](https://ggleblanc.substack.com/p/calendargui), might provide some hints to help you.